# Setup On Premises Data Gateway using Powershell

Tags: powershell, data-gateway

I am trying to setup on-premises data gateway using powershell. i am able to install but i am unable to register with powershell. Can you please provide me step by step how to setup on-premises data gateway using powersehll

Comment: help me to setup on-premises data gateway using powershell

Comment: I didn't get any response from anyone. Can you please help me on that